# Converting LINQ C# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, migration

I'm dealing with this monster:

```
public static IEnumerable<Warp> GetWarps(IEnumerable<Point> sourcePoints, IEnumerable<Point> destPoints, IEnumerable<Triangle> destTriangles)
{
    // build lists of source and destination landmark points
    var sourceList = sourcePoints.ToList();
    var destList = destPoints.ToList();

    // find all three triangle points in the list of destination landmark points
    var indices = from t in destTriangles
                  let p1 = destPoints.First(p => Math.Abs(p.X - t.P1.X) < 1 && Math.Abs(p.Y - t.P1.Y) < 1)
                  let p2 = destPoints.First(p => Math.Abs(p.X - t.P2.X) < 1 && Math.Abs(p.Y - t.P2.Y) < 1)
                  let p3 = destPoints.First(p => Math.Abs(p.X - t.P3.X) < 1 && Math.Abs(p.Y - t.P3.Y) < 1)
                  select new {
                      X1 = destList.IndexOf(p1),
                      X2 = destList.IndexOf(p2),
                      X3 = destList.IndexOf(p3)
                  };

    // return enumeration of warps from source to destination triangles
    return from x in indices
           select new Warp(
               new Triangle(sourceList[x.X1], sourceList[x.X2], sourceList[x.X3]),
               new Triangle(destList[x.X1], destList[x.X2], destList[x.X3]));
}
```

I have tried really much, but I'm not experienced to dealt with the syntax and the pitfalls.

My own approaches all failed, and I have no idea if I'm getting in the right direction at all:

```vb
 Function GetWarps(ByVal sourcePoints As IEnumerable(Of Point), ByVal destPoints As IEnumerable(Of Point), ByVal destTriangles As IEnumerable(Of Triangle)) As IEnumerable(Of Warp)

    Dim sourceList = sourcePoints.ToList()
    Dim destList = destPoints.ToList()

    Dim p1 As Triangle
    Dim p2 As Triangle
    Dim p3 As Triangle

    Dim indices = From t In destTriangles 
        p1 = destPoints.First(Function(p) Math.Abs(p.X - t.P1.X) < 1 AndAlso Math.Abs(p.Y - t.P1.Y) < 1) 
        p2 = destPoints.First(Function(p) Math.Abs(p.X - t.P2.X) < 1 AndAlso Math.Abs(p.Y - t.P2.Y) < 1) 
        p3 = destPoints.First(Function(p) Math.Abs(p.X - t.P3.X) < 1 AndAlso Math.Abs(p.Y - t.P3.Y) < 1) Select
     (
            .X1 = destList.IndexOf(p1), Key,
            .X2 = destList.IndexOf(p2), Key,
            .X3 = destList.IndexOf(p3), Key,
    )
    Return From x In indices Select New Warp(New Triangle(sourceList(x.X1), sourceList(x.X2), sourceList(x.X3)), New Triangle(destList(x.X1), destList(x.X2), destList(x.X3)))

End Function
```

Could anybody tell me how to do that correctly?

Thank you VERY much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!! :-)

```vb
Public Function GetWarps(ByVal sourcePoints As IEnumerable(Of Point), ByVal destPoints As IEnumerable(Of Point), ByVal destTriangles As IEnumerable(Of Triangle)) As IEnumerable(Of Warp)
        ' build lists of source and destination landmark points
        Dim sourceList = sourcePoints.ToList()
        Dim destList = destPoints.ToList()

        ' find all three triangle points in the list of destination landmark points
        Dim indices = From t In destTriangles _
                      Let p1 = destPoints.First(Function(p) Math.Abs(p.X - t.P1.X) < 1 AndAlso Math.Abs(p.Y - t.P1.Y) < 1) Let p2 = destPoints.First(Function(p) Math.Abs(p.X - t.P2.X) < 1 AndAlso Math.Abs(p.Y - t.P2.Y) < 1) Let p3 = destPoints.First(Function(p) Math.Abs(p.X - t.P3.X) < 1 AndAlso Math.Abs(p.Y - t.P3.Y) < 1) _
                      Select New With {Key .X1 = destList.IndexOf(p1), Key .X2 = destList.IndexOf(p2), Key .X3 = destList.IndexOf(p3)}

        ' return enumeration of warps from source to destination triangles
        Return From x In indices _
               Select New Warp(New Triangle(sourceList(x.X1), sourceList(x.X2), sourceList(x.X3)), New Triangle(destList(x.X1), destList(x.X2), destList(x.X3)))
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```vb
Public Shared Function GetWarps(ByVal sourcePoints As IEnumerable(Of Point), ByVal destPoints As IEnumerable(Of Point), ByVal destTriangles As IEnumerable(Of Triangle)) As IEnumerable(Of Warp)
    Dim sourceList = sourcePoints.ToList()
    Dim destList = destPoints.ToList()
    Dim indices = From t In destTriangles Let p1 = destPoints.First(Function(p) Math.Abs(p.X - t.P1.X) < 1 AndAlso Math.Abs(p.Y - t.P1.Y) < 1) Let p2 = destPoints.First(Function(p) Math.Abs(p.X - t.P2.X) < 1 AndAlso Math.Abs(p.Y - t.P2.Y) < 1) Let p3 = destPoints.First(Function(p) Math.Abs(p.X - t.P3.X) < 1 AndAlso Math.Abs(p.Y - t.P3.Y) < 1) Select New With {Key
        .X1 = destList.IndexOf(p1), Key
        .X2 = destList.IndexOf(p2), Key
        .X3 = destList.IndexOf(p3)
    }
    Return From x In indices Select New Warp(New Triangle(sourceList(x.X1), sourceList(x.X2), sourceList(x.X3)), New Triangle(destList(x.X1), destList(x.X2), destList(x.X3)))
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't work due to various errors.

Comment: @tmighty otherwise you could let the function stay in c# and just reference it in vb.net

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: So you need one solution with two projects in it - one C#, the other VB. VB project is your main app and C# project compiles to a class library, you should be able to add a reference to the C# project to your VB project and then make calls from VB code to C# code very easily. You could try to search the web for it. There are some tutorials how to mix / merge c# code with vb.net.

Comment: You can't mix C# and VB in the same project/assembly, but you can add a second assembly/project to a dolution in a different language and then reference it from the first. I don't advise it, whoever looks at your code in a year or three will be scratching his/her head